# javascript engine before nitro (in Mobile Safari)

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

Lots of articles deal with the "new" js engine nitro on iOS.

For developing and comfortable testing for older iOS devices, I would like to install an outdated browser on windows or ubuntu which is using the same js interpreter?

It's so sad that the js interpreter or js engine differs so much, even with parsing scripts.

To find the right WebKit port, I have to know the name of the "old" js engine. Where to find it?

Thanks

Comment: I also would be curious about a specific example where the JS engines differ, specifically in parsing scripts. I can't help but thinking that you either produced invalid JavaScript or ran into a pretty esoteric bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of the pastebin example, there is a syntax error because class is a reserved word and can not be written (with strict js settings like on the old ios webkit).
Use .className instead!

Comment: right, it was the same mistake within the obfuscated js. class -> className fixed the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

To test with different JavaScript engines and browsers I would recommend using the genius [Browserstack](http://www.browserstack.com/). It offers emulators for iOS 3.2 to 6.0 for either the iPhone or iPad. With a comprehensive unit testing suite for your app it should be easy to find engine specific errors.

Comment: I use several emulators and few actual devices and know that the Safari Mobile in iOS4.x is running into troubles with some minified and "obfuscated" javascript. This happens very often! However it is not best practice to look for the error line if it is minified and all javascript packed within one line and sometimes eval() around it. In Chrome and Firefox, debugging is easy, but the error console of iOS (emulator) is not helpful: parsing error in line xy! That's why I really need a webkit browser on my desktop PC which has the same out-dated javascript engine like iOS4.x is using for safari.

Comment: Seems to me as if you are using a bad minifier/obfuscator. The Google Closure compiler or UglifyJS work pretty reliable and tell you problems they might have beforehand. And obfuscating JS is really not worth the effort and additional headache.

Comment: I found another example, where the engine fails. In my opinion, the code is fine, all browsers are able to run it, except iOS4.x: http://pastebin.com/iA64uMpH any idea?

Comment: Yes. `container.class` is a possibly reserve keyword. Try `container['class']`. It will probably work.